# How do I work with local files on a branch in Git?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-merge

Our web team is working on new features and we have two branches right now: master and dev.

Master branch needs constant updating. Master branch content is now ahead of dev by two months. I'd like to add temp content to dev while the web team continues working but I don't want to mess with my master branch files.

I want to leave master branch alone. Should I make a branch off of dev -> dev-2? How do I download and begin working with the files of dev-2 without affecting the master branch? If I download the files from dev branch to my local repo -> when I switch to the master branch won't git think those files now should go into master?

Answer (score 0):

switch to confused master branch

`git checkout master`

backup it:
`git checkout -b master_backup`

delete confused master:

`git branch -D master`

fetch latest changes:

`git fetch --all`

checkout to the latest master:

`git checkout master`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, Instead of making a new branch out of dev, you could make a new branch from master and later merge it with master once you finished with temp content. If develop branch is not similar to master and has a lot of conflicts which is hard to resolve. Trying to create a new branch of master and constantly working on this branch is better.

OR

Just go to develop branch locally on your system and follow the below steps:

```
git checkout master [ switched to master branch ]
git pull [ latest changes will be pulled ]
git merge --no-ff develop [ try to merge develop with master ]
```

Then, you can fix any conflicts if exists by typing below commands

```
git status [ shows the files with conflicts in git ]
code . [ opens in an editor to work with the files ]
```

Then, fix the conflicts and once everything is resolved.

```
git merge develop [ clean merge of develop with master with no conflicts ]
```

Then, go to GitHub and create a pull request to master from develop and this time you won't see any conflicts and merge will be successful.

**Tip:**
Remember, the best way to use GitHub is to have a master branch and a development branch with each individual feature as a new branch created from the development branch. Later merge any individual branch with the development branch and finally merge develop with master if everything is fine. Below is the basic diagram to demonstrate branching in Git

[Git Branching Diagram](https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=1&highlight=0000ff&layers=1&nav=1&title=Untitled%20Diagram.xml#R7VhNc5swEP01XDuA%2BLCPjWOnh2amMzn0rBgZ1MisR8hf%2FfUV1spABIlnktStHS5GTyut9r0HlvDIZLm7k3RV3EPGhBf62c4jt14Yhn6S6J8a2RskJYEBcskzA7WAB%2F6bIegjuuYZqzqBCkAovuqCcyhLNlcdjEoJ227YAkQ364rmzAEe5lRY9Evc4D95pgrEg2TcdHxjPC8w%2BShMTccjnT%2FlEtYlZvRCsjhcpntJ7VxYalXQDLYtiEw9MpEAytwtdxMmanYtcWbcbKD3WI9kpTplQGgGbKhYY%2FH3tFJM4urU3nJyqInVowKP3Cy4EBMQIA%2BdJPBTMtbz31RKwhOzPSWUrAZtjfXIXNKM68U9i1lAqR4wW4DtVoLZ4bJxxjBBpNtuvUjBhknFdi0I679jsGRK7nUI9iYpkrC3%2Fo2t%2FttG%2B9BHxYqW7AliFA2XHydvKNc3yHq%2FAvHIkcAhn2Xan9gEqQrIoaRi2qA3jTy%2BbhVqKZDIX0ypPTJG1wo01MzwHWCFcSZnnWjQSQhVsJZzjCL4dFKZM4yK0362JRNU8U13%2BrcQRxzebtmGCV3RFXk36XqXRL3eDT%2FKu%2BlFvD4cvntUOVmCgdfHR0kQOQrMGFVryf4vCd70FBC%2FK0EU%2F903uCsB310R%2FXF0VvoTh%2F7pbsUkX%2BqKqLgiHUbpWXVw%2FwsKUIurehKC8LwSEN%2FRwGG%2FvZdk4hG27W3kAdAddclcH4iOOthTUE0UK7Ov9SlLNx8FzJ8MNONCtBhvK9CVUmug9ylRfPsS569tMr2%2B7eqgLmFXlSDpUyXoU%2BUI9smC%2BX4A16sfShY2yewcpjgc1j6cPZspGF63ncqQ4kx1MMqRh9O8Y91%2B6d6JPr3z7t5xPyNcpneST%2B%2B8u3fcc%2Fy%2F4J2MVsVxj%2FJGI4WukdJPI71oJC0W3bfCVnVANbzmUex3Fz1OXl6Z%2F%2FzYPrZLa6xsFnGisXWz%2BWxrwpuv42T6Bw%3D%3D)